# Laravel: MariaDB - artisan migrate:refresh hangs

Tags: laravel-5, mariadb, laravel-artisan

I'm using Debian 9 with MariaDB 10.1.27, Composer 1.4.2 and Laravel 5.5.13.

I've created an empty database using `CREATE DATABASE 'laravel'`, configured it in Laravel's `.env` config file and now I've sometimes the problem, that database actions hangs (nothing happens) or in the browser I get an timeout exceeded message. Connecting to the database using `mysql -u laravel -p laravel` is still possible - like `SELECT`'s.

`php artisan migrate`

...is sometimes working like `migrate:refresh` and sometimes not. If it's not working, I always have to restart the MariaDB service and usually, it works then the first time again.

`migrate:refresh` for example clears the database and imports / loads most of the time 10 migrations and then, it's just doing nothing. I've already waited about 1 hour for this task, but it only keeps saying, that the migration table was missing and added and nothing more. Artisan doesn't even say, that it has imported / loaded 9 other tables...

For sending emails, I'm using supervisor, but it shouldn't be in use, while running `migrate:refreshh`;

Increasing the execution timeout doesn't help anything. So, what's the problem? In Homestead it's just working perfect. Are there any specific settings in MariaDB required? Or do I need to create the database with specific parameters like default charset?

Btw: If the application is running, I'm also sometimes getting the execution timeout error message, while browsing the web site.

Comment: Using Laravel 5.5.14, the issue does still exist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using Supervisor to control artisan queues, the deamon should definitely be stopped

```
sudo supervisorctl stop <YOUR_QUEUES>
```

while performing

```
artisan migrate:refresh
```

It will more often than not lead to a kind of race condition, while artisan is trying to lock the table `jobs` to delete it from the database and the Artisan queue is trying to lock the table `jobs` to perform its tasks.

The general query log (for this, I worked with MariaDB 10.1.27) shows something like this:

```
94 Prepare   drop table if exists `jobs`
63 Query     START TRANSACTION
67 Query     SAVEPOINT trans2
67 Prepare   select * from `jobs` where `queue` = ? and ((`reserved_at` is null and `available_at` <= ?) or (`reserved_at` <= ?)) order by `id` asc limit 1 for update
67 Execute   select * from `jobs` where `queue` = 'user' and ((`reserved_at` is null and `available_at` <= 1511429487) or (`reserved_at` <= 1511429397)) order by `id` asc limit 1 for update
67 Close stmt
```

While the artisan:refresh command *hangs*, and `jobs` is being queued by Supervisor-powered job worker, the MariaDB server reports two connections (from the Laravel DB user in question) waiting for metadata lock.

At first I also went with restarting MariaDB, which solved the problem in a not so clean way. But then, stopping Supervisor, made the difference.

Comment: Makes sense. Is there any known solution, which autom. stops Supervisor while doing such jobs?